# Java - Class-wide Generic Type that is NOT Separately Specified For Instantiation

Tags: java, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to reference a nested generic parameter in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996871/is-it-possible-to-reference-a-nested-generic-parameter-in-java)

A quick question on Java generics if I may. Is there syntax for declaring a generic class-wide type that is NOT used as a generic parameter for instantiation. For example:

```
public class <U extends FooUType> BarType<T extends FooType<U>>{

   public U getU(){return U;}
}
```

To create a BarType I want to write the following, which in itself contains U, but I don't want to have to specify U separately. So:

```
BarType<SomeT<FooUType>> instance
```

We get the type of U implicitly from the parameterized SomeT without having to specify U separately. As opposed to :

```
public class BarType<U extends FooUType, T extends FooType<U>>
```

which would require:

```
BarType<FooUType,SomeT<FooUType>>
```

I guess I'm looking for something akin to the same idea in methods:

```
public <U> boolean StupidMethod(String s){
    ...
}
```

I would rather not use `<? extends FooUType>` as this leads to problems with method return types inside the class that return `<U extends FooUType> U`.

Many thanks for the clarification!

Comment: This is worse than finding out Santa doesn't exist :( At least then I got presents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks all,

I went for a different solution in the end. Basically the class I was trying to hide the `U` in was abstract and so I added `U` as a generic parameter as there is no way round this. I then created the concrete classes that extend this and had them fill in the type of `U` silently so that the caller wouldn't need to bloat their code.

Something like this:

```
public abstract class MyAbsClass<U extends Foo, T extends Bar<U>>{...}

public class ConcreteClass<T extends SomeBar> extends MyAbsClass<SilentUType, T>
```

where `SomeBar` is not parameterized. The user can then just instantiate with `T`:

```
 new ConcreteClass<SomeDerivedBar>()
```

This worked for my scenario neatly, so I hope it helps others.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments said, this isn't possible.

> I would rather not use `<? extends FooUType>` as this leads to problems with method return types inside the class that return `<U extends FooUType> U`.

So, here you're saying that some methods of the class return `U`... yet you don't want to have  `U` as a type parameter. Well, you can't have it both ways. Either have this:

```
public class BarType<T extends FooType<U>, U extends FooUType>{

   public U getU() { ... }
}
```

Or this:

```
public class BarType<T extends FooType<? extends FooUType>>{

   public FooUType getU() { ... }
}
```

If it's just the noisy instantiation you're concerned with, you can use `new BarType<>` where applicable with Java 7. Without Java 7, declare a factory method so the callers can use type inference:

```
public static <T extends FooType<U>, U extends FooUType> BarType<T, U> make() {
    return new BarType<T, U>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I went a slightly different route after considering everyone's input. I've posted my solution as an answer in case it helps others.