# Referring to "nested" generic parameter in Java

Tags: java, generics

Suppose I have:

```
class A<T> {
...
}

class B<L extends A<?>> {
...
}
```

Within the scope of B, is there any way to refer to the "nested" generic parameter T of the type represented by L? (not at runtime obviously)

All I could find was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996871/is-it-possible-to-reference-a-nested-generic-parameter-in-java), which did not answer my question.

Comment: How does the other question not answer your question?  What's wrong with `class B<T, L extends A<T>>`?

Comment: `?` is going to get erased to type Object.  But in general no, there's no (reasonable) way to get that type.  Large complicated libraries do exist to extract that sort of thing, if you must.  But consider using a [type token](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html).

Comment: @rgettman Suppose that T is not relevant for 99% of the code - it's a shame to drag the deceleration of T everywhere with you just for the 1%...

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, that's exactly what you're asking for -- the `T` from `A` in `B`.  And I think you mean "declaration".

Comment: if `T` is not relevant most of the times, you can use `?` for it, i.e. use type `B<?, Foo<Bar>>` in most places ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only occasionally need to refer to the type represented by `?` it would be awkward and annoying to make it `class B<T, L extends A<T>>`.

What you can do instead is use generic helper methods every time you need to refer to `T`.

For example:

```
<T, L extends A<T>> void foo(L l) {
    // You can refer to both L and T here
}
```

Within `B`, if you have a variable `var` of type `L` you can do

```
foo((A<?>) var)
```

Here is a full example:

```
public class Example {

    static class A<T> {}

    static class B<L extends A<?>> {

        void bar(L l) {
            foo((A<?>) l);
        }
    }

    static <T, L extends A<T>> void foo(L l) {
        // You can refer to both L and T here
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ofer I don't know. I've been experimenting with this for the past 15 minutes. I can't understand why `foo(var)` doesn't compile, but it doesn't.

Comment: I removed that question before you replied, I think I know why the (A<?>) casting is necessary: It's because the L in the deceleration of foo is not the same L as in the deceleration of B!
Thanks again :)

Comment: hmmmm it doesn't actually explains it :(

Comment: @Ofer No I can't understand it. Every time I think I understand generics, I get caught out.

Comment: @PaulBoddington - how do you mean? `foo(var)` seems working for me. Although, it probably requires java8.

Comment: @bayou.io Interesting. I'm using `javac 1.8.0_25` and I get `Error:(15, 13) java: method foo in class Main cannot be applied to given types;
  required: L
  found: L
  reason: inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)`

Comment: I'm on version `_60`. apparently, the upper bound of `foo.L` is used to infer `foo.T` too!

Comment: does `foo( (A<T>) var)` compile too?

Comment: @bayou.io I don't know what you mean. I'm in `B` so there is no `T`.

Comment: @bayou.io Yes. I'll edit my answer to show exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: yeah, withdraw my previous comments:) yes, an upcast to `A<?>` is needed in v60 too. possibly related - [this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/java-lang-fans/KVmmgeSCHkA/Ypc0Ewr-mUMJ) and [this](http://bayou.io/draft/Wildcard_Case_Studies.html#Unexpected_Non-Capture)

Comment: @bayou.io It's weird isn't it. Is there any obscure corner of Java you haven't written about?

Comment: tip of the iceberg... java type system is too complicated, there are probably infinite number of corners.